# dpkg pre-depends on libbz2-1.0 error

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to upgrade a friends Ubuntu from 14 to 16.04 and have run into the above problem. I followed the instructions below because I was having the problem..."required dependency 'dpkg (>= 1.17.5ubuntu5.6)' is not installed."

Step 1.

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

OR (Depending on your system)

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.6_i386.deb
```

Step 2.

```
sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

When I ran Step 2 I got `dpkg pre-depends on libbz2-1.0`. I then tried to install `libbz2-1.0` but it is already installed.

Just in case I tried to trigger the update again by using

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

but got the initial "required dependency `dpkg (>= 1.17.5ubuntu5.6)' is not installed.` error again.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Fixed. I don't know whether I typed something in incorrectly first time round but I restarted the laptop, followed the above process again and it worked perfectly.